Uploading video to blogger from NodeJS
I am trying to upload video to blogger using following code. I am able to get the response from my code. I am getting stuck at, that I am not able to transfer the video data to blogger.
My NodeJS code:
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const videoPath = '/Downloads/11H3Bepq6Hx_seEhq2iO7OSW1zC01PnKo.mp4';
const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath);

let data = '{"protocolVersion":"0.8","createSessionRequest":{"fields":[{"external":{"name":"file","filename":"11H3Bepq6Hx_seEhq2iO7OSW1zC01PnKo.mp4","put":{},"size":1018020}},{"inlined":{"name":"title","content":"11H3Bepq6Hx_seEhq2iO7OSW1zC01PnKo.mp4","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"addtime","content":"1726417159033","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"onepick_version","content":"v2","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"onepick_host_id","content":"10","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"onepick_host_usecase","content":"RichEditor","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"tos","content":"true","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"blogID","content":"add-your-own-id-here","contentType":"text/plain"}},{"inlined":{"name":"postID","content":"add-your-own-id-here","contentType":"text/plain"}}]}}';

let config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://docs.google.com/upload/blogger/resumable?authuser=0&opi=98421741',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Host': 'docs.google.com',
        'Origin': 'https://docs.google.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15',
        'Referer': 'https://docs.google.com/',
        'Content-Length': '860',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Cookie': '',
        'X-Goog-Upload-Header-Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        'X-Goog-Upload-Header-Content-Length': '1018020',
        'X-Client-Pctx': 'CgcSBWjtl_cu',
        'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': 'resumable',
        'X-Goog-Upload-Command': 'start'
    },
    data: data
};

axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        
        const boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
        const body = `--${boundary}\r\n` +
            `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"\r\n\r\n` +
            `${data}\r\n` +
            `--${boundary}\r\n` +
            `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="${path.basename(videoPath)}"\r\n` +
            `Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n` +
            `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n` +
            `${fs.readFileSync(videoPath, { encoding: 'binary' })}\r\n` +
            `--${boundary}--`;

        let config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://docs.google.com/upload/blogger/resumable?authuser=0&opi=98421741&upload_id=${response.data['sessionStatus']['upload_id']}&upload_protocol=resumable`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `multipart/related; boundary=${boundary}`,
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
                'Host': 'docs.google.com',
                'Origin': 'https://docs.google.com',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15',
                'Referer': 'https://docs.google.com/',
                'Content-Length': '1018020',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
                'Cookie': '',
                "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol": "multipart",
            },
            "cache": "default",
            "credentials": "include",
            "mode": "cors",
            "redirect": "follow",
            "referrer": "https://docs.google.com/",
            "referrerPolicy": "origin",
            data: body
        };

        axios.request(config)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

The response I am getting from blogger:
{"sessionStatus":{"state":"FINALIZED","externalFieldTransfers":[{"name":"file","status":"COMPLETED","bytesTransferred":0,"bytesTotal":1018020,"putInfo":{"url":"https://docs.google.com/upload/blogger/resumable?authuser=0&opi=98421741&upload_protocol=resumable&upload_id=AD-8ljsco6WMZdutraflzfW1AtmJ1k5OYO2PudwjgaYof8PaCSqRn5kqZofxDnlNtVlaig95-jM&file_id=000"},"content_type":"video/mp4"}],"additionalInfo":{"uploader_service.GoogleRupioAdditionalInfo":{"completionInfo":{"status":"SUCCESS"}}},"upload_id":"AD-8ljsco6WMZdutraflzfW1AtmJ1k5OYO2PudwjgaYof8PaCSqRn5kqZofxDnlNtVlaig95-jM"}}

You see the bytesTransferred shows 0. It means video data is not transferred.
When tranferring through browser, response generated is as follows:
{"sessionStatus":{"state":"FINALIZED","externalFieldTransfers":[{"name":"file","status":"COMPLETED","bytesTransferred":1018020,"bytesTotal":1018020,"putInfo":{"url":"https://docs.google.com/upload/blogger/resumable?authuser=0\u0026opi=98421741\u0026upload_id=AD-8ljvGMD4Mg6k6oSxW74UCa0gsZKJt3grXpwNS6UFtbCnu0D-HyPXF5_B_Krr1aJ-mZQjJ3jcicPLGUSAARAl4TJdDosvQiwltu-Xd139T0aI0\u0026file_id=000"},"content_type":"video/mp4"}],"additionalInfo":{"uploader_service.GoogleRupioAdditionalInfo":{"completionInfo":{"status":"SUCCESS","customerSpecificInfo":{"contentId": "ed34314396d57090"}}}},"upload_id":"AD-8ljvGMD4Mg6k6oSxW74UCa0gsZKJt3grXpwNS6UFtbCnu0D-HyPXF5_B_Krr1aJ-mZQjJ3jcicPLGUSAARAl4TJdDosvQiwltu-Xd139T0aI0"}}

Here bytesTransferred is 1018020 same as bytesTotal.
Upon more research, I came across this code:
h.Xc = function() {
        var a = yd(this.Ca);
        this.V.length != null && (a["Content-Length"] = this.V.length);
        a = fac(a);
        a["X-Goog-Upload-Protocol"] = "multipart";
        a["Content-Type"] = "multipart/related; boundary=" + this.U;
        this.H = "Transferring";
        this.N = new DZ;
        this.O.te();
        this.O.listen(this.N, "progress", this.pda);
        this.O.listen(this.N, "complete", this.oda);
        var b = this.N,
            c = b.send,
            d = this.Ia,
            e = this.Ha,
            f = "--" + this.U + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"\r\n\r\n' + (this.Ga + "\r\n--") + this.U + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: ' +
            (this.La + "\r\n\r\n") + this.V + "\r\n--" + this.U + "--\r\n";
        this.wa = f.length - this.V.length;
        c.call(b, d, e, f, a)
    };

But still the error is there. In my code, to simulate please login in blogger. Grab cookie value. Also replace add-your-own-id-here in data variable with appropriate values.
Thank You
